# What a green P stands for in MPLAB IDE watch list?

Tags: debugging, mplab, ide

Hello I'm debugging a C program in MPLAB IDE 8.92 and I have a green P at left o a variable in the watch list.
Does somebody knows what it means?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Please reload, I updated the original post.

Comment: @E_Blue no you didnt.

Comment: @efox29. It was posted for a few minutes, then deleted for reasons unknown.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I'm sorry I try to edit the image position because I get the image over the text when I attached the first time so I delete it and reload the image.

Answer (score 3):

The **P** indicates that the memory address that is being watched points to a variable stored in the **P**rogram memory (ROM) of the device rather than in the RAM.

We can see this in another example taken from [here](http://www.puntoflotante.net/BOLT-SYSTEM-SIMULATING-POINTERS-MPLAB.htm):

[image: ROM vs RAM in Watch window]

Notice how there is a **P** next to the arrays stored in the ROM.

Comment: Shucks, you found it before I did, and I did a lot of searching. I also have an older version of MPLAB.

Comment: @Sparky256 I've seen it before when working with MPLAB, but was busy so didn't have time to answer.

Comment: Can that happen even if I declared the variable as a char cmdTSBits?

Comment: @E_Blue you'd have to show your code.

Comment: All or just the declarations?

Comment: @E_Blue declarations will probably do. Preferably a snippet of where you use `cmd_TSBits` too.